# "UnboundLocalError: local variable referenced before assignment" when incrementing variable in function

Tags: python

I am getting this error and I've read other posts but they say to put `global` before `dollars = 0` which produces a syntax error because it doesn't allow the `= 0`. I'm using `dollars` as a counter so I can keep track of what I add to it and display it back when needed.

```
dollars = 0

def sol():
    print('Search or Leave?')
    sol = input()
    if sol == 'Search':
        search()
    if sol == 'Leave':
        leave()

def search():
    print('You gain 5 bucks')
    dollars = dollars + 5
    shop()

def leave():
    shop()

def shop():
    shop = input()
    if shop == 'Shortsword':
        if money < 4:
            print('I\'m sorry, but you don\'t have enough dollars to buy that item.')
            shop1()
        if money > 4:
            print('Item purchased!')
            print('You now have ' + dollars + ' dollars.')

sol()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/justin/Python/Programs I Made/Current/Testing.py", line 29, in <module>
    sol()
  File "C:/Users/justin/Python/Programs I Made/Current/Testing.py", line 7, in sol
    search()
  File "C:/Users/justin/Python/Programs I Made/Current/Testing.py", line 13, in search
    dollars = dollars + 5
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dollars' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: What is supposed to happen if `money == 4`?

Comment: Could you please post the full traceback?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to add `global dollars`, like follows

```
def search():
    global dollars
    print('You gain 5 bucks')
    dollars = dollars + 5
    shop()
```

Everytime you want to change a `global` variable inside a function, you need to add this statement, you can just access the `dollar` variable without the `global` statement though,

```
def shop():
    global dollars
    shop = input("Enter something: ")
    if shop == 'Shortsword':
        if dollars < 4:          # Were you looking for dollars?
            print('I\'m sorry, but you don\'t have enough dollars to buy that item.')
            shop1()
        if dollars > 4:
            print('Item purchased!')
            dollars -= someNumber # Change Number here
            print('You now have ' + dollars + ' dollars.')
```

You also need to reduce the dollars, when you shop for something!

P.S - I hope you're using Python 3, you'll need to use `raw_input` instead.

Comment: Noo, don't patch it! I was exploiting my thousand shortswords!

Comment: @Haidro : I'd like to shop like this too. :P

Comment: I did what was suggested, however, now it just prints You gain 5 bucks then shows a blank. It doesn't go to shop for whatever reason.

Comment: Works fine here. Except that the variable `money` is not defined. Did you mean `dollars`? Beware that since you did not pass anything to `input`, the interpreter is waiting for input with a blank screen. Try the changed code.

Comment: Oh wow! I can't believe I missed that.. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put `global dollars`, on a line on its own, inside any function where you change the value of dollars. In the code you've shown that is only in `search()`, although I assume you'll also want to do it inside `shop()` to subtract the value of the item you buy...