# UnboundLocalError while return : Python

Tags: python, boto3

I have a python boto3 code as below:

```
for rule in event_rules:
        if rule.startswith('Something'):
            print('[INFO] Proceeding!...')
            describe_rule = self.cw_event.describe_rule(
                Name=rule
            )
            if describe_rule['State'] == 'ENABLED':
                state = True
                break
        else:
            state = False
    return state
    .
    .
    .
if check == True:
       print('[INFO] SUCCESS' )          

else:
       print('[INFO] FAILED')
```

Here *check* is the class function which calls the above block from its function.I am pretty confident on the function and class part.
In this case when a rule is present and is in ENABLED state,code is successfull. If the conditions are not matching, it throws out an error as follows:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'state' referenced before assignment

I am not able to figure it out. I went through this answer : [UnBoundLocalError: Local Variable Referenced Before Assignment [Counter]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17521410/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-referenced-before-assignment-counter) and gave *state* as global, but still failed.

Comment: You should specify which line throws the error, the exception should tell you.

Comment: @Bernhard error throws at ```return state```;
line number 12

Comment: In that case, see my anwser, if you hit the first, but miss the second if statement,  `state` is not yet assigned .

Comment: @Bernhard but even if the first if cases fails,  throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should probably specify where the exception gets thrown, but at first look, if you get into `if rule.startswith('Something'):` but don't hit the second if statement `[State] == 'ENABLED'` then state won't be initiated and might throw the error on the return statement.